# ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, data-warehouse

ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed because column does not have the same ANSI trimming semantics in tables...

Does anyone knows how to fix that on already existing table full of data?

Well, I've found that it is simply possible to recreate same table with same ANSI_PADDING parameter, but the problem is that the table I'm trying to switch into a larger main table is already filled with data. I don't want to spend again 37 hours to reload that partition =(

Comment: The problematic column has different setting "ansi padding status" on source and target tables. Obviously because I didn't pay attention to it when was creating staging table. Is there way to alter this property?

Comment: Look at the bright side: next time you'll know!

Comment: I like your optimism)) For now it appeared that there two more tables with the same problem so overall reload time will become ~50h.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say this, but there's a bug in Books Online. The [Books Online page on partition switching](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) says:

> Source and target tables must have the same column structure and
>   order. The tables must have the same columns with the same names and
>   the same data type, length, collation, precision, scale, nullability,
>   and PRIMARY KEY constraints (if any), and also have the same settings
>   for ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED IDENTIFIER.

But as you've discovered ANSI_PADDING is also involved - both the incoming & outgoing tables have to have the same setting. There is no way to fix this after the data is loaded.

Answer (score -2):

create the create table script of source table , modify the create table script as to create a new target table then run the switch command again

Comment: -1 this doesn't address "the problem is that the table I'm trying to switch into a larger main table is already filled with data. I don't want to spend again 37 hours to reload that partition"